# warning: passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers

Tags: c, gcc-warning

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char original[5] = ".txt";
    int c;
    strcat(argv[1], original);
    FILE *find;
    find = fopen( argv[1], "r");
    if (find) {
        while ((c = getc(find)) != EOF)
            putchar(c);
        fclose(find);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

What will I do? 
Now, i creating a project with c programming.

Answer (score 2):

```
strcat(argv[1], original);
```

The type of `argv[1]` is `const char*`, and the first argument of `strcat` is `char*`.

The strings in `argv` are not supposed to be modified.

You basically need this (there is still room for improvement):

```
char txtextension[5] = ".txt";
char filename[200];  // 200 will be hopefully enough 
strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
strcat(filename, txtextension);
FILE *find;
find = fopen(filename, "r");
```

**Sidenotes**:

1. Replace `char original[5] = ".txt";` with `char original[] = ".txt";`. In the latter case the compiler automatically allocates the correct memory size.
2. Name variables according to what they represent, so `original` should be named  for example `txtextension`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now my program can run .
#I'm not good at English. So sorry if i write wrong sentence.

Comment: If the answer is what you needed, you should accept it by clicking on the outlined checkmark, so other people know that the answer was useful.

Comment: There should be a `PATH_MAX` define in `limits.h` (or `MAX_PATH` in Windows) for the array size, if you do not want to hope that 200 is enough.

Comment: @MichaelWalz "The strings in argv are not supposed to be modified" - actually, the C standard explicitly states that the strings in argv shall be modifiable... (C++ - not referenced here - does not seem to be specific about that at all, though.)

Comment: @Aconcagua modified maybe, but `strcat` will certainly be a problem.

Comment: The C standard allows you to modify them indeed... but it is not a very smart thing to do in most cases. I'm not quite sure why you would ever want to do that... sounds like muddy program design to me. I'm pretty sure C allows this just because of some backwards-compatibility crap.

Comment: @MichaelWalz As will be with any char array being too short to hold the entire concatenated content...

Comment: @Lundin Not quite sure any more - didn't getopt exactly do that for options recognised (and leave the unrecognised ones)?